# Vertex inside a triangle - Collision detection

Tags: c++, geometry, collision-detection

I am trying to check whether a Vertex is inside an triangle , but i have problems developping a CCW function for a 3D enviroment.

for a 2D enviroment CCW function would be like that

```
//CCW calculates the cross produt


double CCW ( point A  , point B , point C ) {

return (B.x-A.x)  * (C.y-A.y) - (B.y-A.y) * (C.x-A.x);

}

//The other part is designed to work on 3D

typedef struct{

   double x;
   double y;
   double z;

}Point;

int inTriangle(point A, point B, point C, point D){

   Point E;

   E.x = (A.x + B.x + C.x)/3;

   E.y = (A.y + B.y + C.y)/3;

   E.z = (A.z + B.z + C.z)/3;


return ( CCW(A,B,D) * CCW (A,B,E) > 0 &&
         CCW(B,C,D) * CCW(B,C,E) > 0 &&
         CCW(A,C,D) * CCW(A,C,E) );

}
```

Comment: CCW can't be calculating the cross product because the cross product is a vector. And beyond that, the cross product is only defined for two vectors.

Comment: OK so it looks like CCW is calculating the z-component of the cross product of vectors AB and AC?

Comment: What does it mean for a point being in triangle for 3D? Do you mean the projection of a point to the plane of the triangle and then checking 2D?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the vertex lies directly in the plane of the triangle and inside the bounds of it (i.e., on the surface of the triangle), you can check those two things seperately.  First check to see if the vertex lies in the plane of the triangle.  Then you should be able to project the triangle and vertex into 2D and use your 2D method.

It also has the benefit of eliminating a lot of vertices because they are not on the plane of the triangle, which is a quick computation.

Answer (score 0):

If the point is on the plane of the triangle, you may use a barycentric method described [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html).

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is to apply this code for testing collision detection between 3d models.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the point is on triangles's plane you can write the triangle's plane equation. It it simple to write using 3 points and it's is linear so the computations will be very fast.

To understand how to write the equation check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry), it's simple.

To determine if the point is in the plane simple check that it's satisfy plain's equation with enough for you accuracy